# To Paginate the Html Table

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to create a table such that when there are more than 10 rows I want to create a hyperlink which tells the user to go on the next page. The concept is called pagination, but how can I acheive it with AngularJS?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Table</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            th {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }
            th td {
                 border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>Heading1</th>
            <th>Heading2</th>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AngularUtils**

Try using the Pagination Directive [here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) by AngularUtils.

Their documentation is very good and they have full instructions on how to get it to work with examples and a demo in Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview).

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
      <li dir-paginate="meal in meals | filter:q | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">{{ meal }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```